# How do I generate random numbers in CUDA FORTRAN?

Tags: random, cuda, fortran

I'm looking for a simple way to generate a random floats between 0.0 and 1.0 for multiple threads in parallel. This is my kernel so far..

```
  attributes(global) subroutine rand_kernel()
     implicit none

     integer :: tid
     real :: r

     ! Thread ID
     tid = threadIdx%x

     ! Generate random number
     call <some random number generator> (r)

     ! Randomise array
     d_array(tid) = r

   end subroutine rand_kernel
```

I've been looking around in forums and reading the CURAND manual, but I still can't figure out what to do. I'm not even sure if there are any random number libraries for CUDA FORTRAN.
I just need a push in a right direction then I can write myself a decent random number generator.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an article explaining how to call a CUDA C implemented pseudo-random number generator (the Mersenne Twister implementation from the CUDA SDK) from a CUDA Fortran code.

Details can be found in the section "Calling a CUDA C Random Number Generator" of this article:
http://www.pgroup.com/lit/articles/insider/v2n1a4.htm

Comment: You could use the same technique to interface to CURAND.

Comment: Sure, but I would not recommend the generators embedded in CURAND since they are stated as bad quality generators by many scientific studies.

Answer (score 1):

you have to generate random numbers in FORTRAN and transfer it to device.

```
call random_number(pkf)

pkf_dev=pkf
```